# windows 10 update stuck on download 0%

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 Anniversary Update, I went to the update page and it started checking for updates (I know I don't need to do this due to auto updating).  I could not tell what it wanted to update, but it went immediately to "DOWNLOADING 0%" and was stuck here for half an hour.  I rebooted and when I went back to the update screen it said that I shutdown in the middle of an "INSTALL" and I clicked on the "Retry".

Can you please tell me why it says in the middle of an install instead of a download?

Now, if I check update history or check for new updates it says the last update was successful a month ago and there are NO updates.  Can someone please explain where this update went?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more specific information.

Comment: Windows 10 anniversary update.  In update , checking for updates stuck on downloading 0% for half an hour.  After reboot ,it said I was in the middle of a install when rebooted.  I clicked on retry,  no updates to be found anywhere.  no updates in history no updates in search for updates.  Can you please tell me where my update(s) went?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: What logs? Can you please explain where I check the logs. I say this while I try to search for the logs myself.

Comment: I followed along with the following link, except to start downloading public symbols, which seems an overly complex tangent from my question https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/charlesa_us/2015/08/06/windows-10-windowsupdate-log-and-how-to-view-it-with-powershell-or-tracefmt-exe/

Comment: Event viewer shows benign updates.if I rebooted during an update install would it show in the event viewer?

Comment: get the latest update via WU catalog: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3201845 and install the MSU on your own

Comment: Same problem here.  None of my Windows 10 computers will update anymore.  They all "stick" at some low percentage of downloading and seem to die there.  Never moves, will go hours without network activity.  :-(